# Make Custom Drawable Shape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I want to make drawable like below,

[image]

I am able to make the Rectangle and Triange  shape in two different xml files. But i want to joint them to make the drawable like this.

Comment: you need a  [<layer-list>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Comment: If you have image of it, why to use drawable?

Comment: If I correctly understood the need of such drawable, you may try 9-patch image.. and just make the rectangular area scalable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `layer-list` to make this custom shape `drawable`.

**/res/drawable/custom_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Transparent Rectangle -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Colored Rectangle -->
    <item
        android:bottom="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#9A8585" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Bottom Triangle -->
    <item
        android:left="80dp"
        android:right="120dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="30dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#9A8585" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- Top Border -->
    <item
        android:bottom="75dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#EFC1B3" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 3):

Use `<layer-list/>` for that.

Here is an example for instance.

in `Drawable` folder of `res`in project directory,
make `xml` file and name it as `layerlist.xml` and paste it below code as your requirement. 
you can also add your shape drawable instead of drawable in the `<item/>` tag in the example. and use this xml as a background of `ImageView`.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item>
>       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
>         android:gravity="center" />
>     </item>
>     <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
>       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
>         android:gravity="center" />
>     </item>
>     <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
>       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
>         android:gravity="center" />
>     </item>
> </layer-list>
> ```

Here is the result of the use of `<layer-list/>`.

[image]

I hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you need it for a a `Tabular` navigator or a `ViewPager`. My suggestion is that

1)Use the rectangle as your background for all the cases.

2)Create the same triangle drawable but with the background color (White or transparent) for the unselected item.

3)Create a view with the triangle background for all the items

4)Manually `setVisibility` of the triangle view according to the selection state